# How to use git submodule with a 3rd party library?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I want to add a 3rd party lib on github as a git submodule for a project I'm working on.

Since this is a library that can change, and those changes are out of my hands, I was wondering  what is the best practice for using it as a submodule.

The options I had in mind are:

1. Forking the lib and using that as a sub module to ensure no changes harm my project.
2. Using a specific version's branch/tag (is that possible) as a submodule

Is one of these options the recommended way to go? Is there a better way aside these options?

Comment: `submodules` reference a commit. You don't have to worry about the library changing as you are responsible for updating the version (i.e the referenced commit) of the library you're using

Comment: So the only reason to fork and use that as the submodule is if I want to make customisations to the lib?

Comment: There's plenty of reasons to use or not to use submodules. For nested dependencies submodules are great. If you need changes to the lib not so much

Comment: So what is recommended if I need to make changes to the lib?

Answer (score 1):

- If this library owner publish packages, it might be easier to use your language manager: you'll just have to update the version number you want to use when a new package is available.
- Otherwise, using submodules (or [subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/)) might be an option. As stated in the comments, you'll still get to choose the commit of the library you want to use, and you'll update whenever you choose to.

As an example, this [project](https://github.com/gturri/dokuJClient) used successively both solutions: it [started](https://github.com/gturri/dokuJClient/blob/d8d607b1216efc438acb492140cf99c5ef752569/.gitmodules) with submodules, and [eventually](https://github.com/gturri/dokuJClient/blob/master/pom.xml#L22) referenced this library as a maven package.

Note that using submodules, you'll end up cloning the library in your workspace, so there's not really any point in wondering if you need to fork the library.